# Unable to load JSON files using karma-read-json plugin

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

my folder structure looks like:

```
 src
   -cars
      car.controller.js
      car.controller.spec.js
      car.test-data.json
```

in my spec file I am reading the json file as follows:

```
var sampleData = readJSON('./car.test-data.json')
```

However I keep receiving the error.. file not found.

I have tried a bunch of different paths.. none seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

I finally went with an alternate solution I found on a blog:

```
mockedDashboardJSON.js:

'use strict'
angular.module('mockedDashboardJSON',[])
.value('defaultJSON',{
    fakeData1:{'really':'fake2'},
    fakeData2:{'history':'faked'}
});
Then in your test file:

beforeEach(module('yourApp','mockedDashboardJSON'));
var YourControlNameCtrl, scope, $httpBackend, mockedDashboardJSON;
beforeEach(function(_$httpBackend_,defaultJSON){
    $httpBackend.when('GET','yourAPI/call/here').respond(defaultJSON.fakeData1);
    //Your controller setup 
    ....
});

it('should test my fake stuff',function(){
    $httpBackend.flush();
    //your test expectation stuff here
    ....
}
```